# Hadoop Mapreduce - top n and bottom n values from a list of 10000 pairs

Tags: java, hadoop, mapreduce

I have a 3000+ key value pair of strings and long data types from a mapreduce programs reducer part.. say {"Aman":2.121212,"Bob": 0.343434} . How to get the top 10 and bottom 10 entries based on Values in mapreduce?

### top 10

1. {100 , Rock}
   2.{99.98765, Balboa}
   .
   .
   .

### bottom 10

1. {0.00976, Tardis}
   2.{0.555, Taqif}
   .
   .

etc

One solution I have is to have them map {1:"Aman|2.1222"}, {1: "Bob|0.343434" }.....etc and then in reduce phase string split value. Use a treemap and list to store all the values. Emit treemaps first ten and call teh descending map interface and emit last 10.

this is very inefficient!.I am using Java API solely to get the top and botton ten key value pair

I want to use map reduce effectively to acheive this!

Answer (score 2):

It is fairly simple problem. Just emit top 10 and bottom 10 from each and every map task and then in single reducer, just find the final top/bottom 10 from all the records. In this case, you are not going to get too many records in single reducer because you are just emitting only 20 records from each map task. Note one thing: From mappers emit one flag with every records saying it is top-10 or bottom-10 data.

Let me know if any further help required.

Comment: how do you emit top ten from each map task? I m new to this MR framework. kindly help with examples

I though map can have only one line at a tiime..eg:{100 , Rock} and next map will have random {0.555, Taqif} .
etc..

Comment: Just have a collection which can maintain top-10 elements. For every new element in the map task just check if the smallest element of the collection is less than the new one. If Yes, then replace older one with new one otherwise  skip the new element. Do same logic for bottom-10 also. Hope this will help.